# Yii layout not displaying

Tags: php, yii

I am working on an existing project written in PHP and using the Yii framework.

I want to create a completely new layout. Under views/layouts I created a file called bootstrap.php and filled this with the standard template I want to use for all pages. I put the  line where I want the content to be placed in between the layout.

In the controller, before I render the view, I call:

```
$this->layout = "//layouts/bootstrap";
```

I would expect this to force the layout to use my new one, however it always reverts back to the main.php layout.

If I change this too a non-existing layout
$this->layout = "//layouts/bootstrapxx";

It will render the page with a blank layout (just outputting the content directly to the browser). This indicates to me that Yii detects the location of my new layout, however it is still rendering the old layout regardless.

If anyone can help me figure out how to set the layout to the new one, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: just refer to `bootstrap`, not `//layouts/bootstrap`

Comment: Thanks, just after I posted the question I did that and it worked. Do you know why it will push me to the main layout doing //layouts/bootstrap as opposed to just giving me blank or an error?

Comment: You can see the logic in [CControler::render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#render-detail) (click the 'show' link to see the source).  If it can't get the layout file, it'll just go on w/o applying a layout . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii layouts should be referenced relative to the layout path (defaults to `protected/views/layouts`), which has a getter and a setter in be determined with [getLayoutPath()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#getLayoutPath-detail) and [setLayoutPath()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#setLayoutPath-detail) respectively.

So, to get your code to work, just refer to the `bootstrap` not, `//layouts/bootstrap`

The application of the layout is handled in [CControler::render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#render-detail)